# How to change Apache to serve a subdirectory by default

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, dokuwiki

I have a vanilla install of DokuWiki on CentOS 6.4 with Apache. The internal URL is

```
http://wiki/dokuwiki
```

How do I go about configuring Apache/DokuWiki to *not* require the `/dokuwiki` part? I want users just to be able to go to:

```
http://wiki
```

in their browser.

Answer (score 3):

Look for the [`DocumentRoot` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)  in your Apache configuration files. It should usually be in one of these:

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`
- `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

It should point to `/var/www`, but if your Wiki is saved in `/var/www/dokuwiki`, then this should be your server's document root, and all pages will be served relative to that directory.

Comment: Thanks slhck, I'll try that tomorrow. From the concise and informative  reply and the amendments you made I'm confident that it's the correct answer.Thanks. Dave.